# How to make Vuejs watcher react to the watched variable change in a sibling?

Tags: vue.js

I have **Search.vue** (parent), from where I pass as prop api_url to **List.vue** (child1), where a watcher of this variable is installed and reloads the list of entities received from API-endpoints every time the user changes filter values (located in parent).

Also I have **Post.vue** (child2), where the form is located adding one more entity to the DB through API-endpoint.

My goal is to make the whole structure reload list of entities automatically every time "submit" button is pressed in child2.

I tried this in child2:

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            api_url: "",
.......
    methods:{
        submitForm(){
            axios.post('api/v1/houses', this.form)
                 .then((res) => {
                    api_url='api/v1/houses'
```

but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways you can make this work.

First one is to use a state management library like [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) or [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). That would allow you to create global states that can be accessed/changed/watched by any of the 3 components you mentioned, regardless of their hierarchy.

Second option would be to make your parent component (Search.vue) responsible for managing all the data flow and turn your children components into dummy ones -- i.e. they would just receive props from their parents with all the data they need, and emit events to their parents when something important happens. Thus, the child2 (Post.vue) component would emit an event like `this.$emit('submitButtonClicked')` to the parent. The parent would react to the event by loadin any data needed (calling an API in your case I assume) and provide the data as a prop to child1 (List.vue).

Comment: `provide` and `inject` are something worth looking into. this is the vanilla vue way of handeling shared state without *prop-drilling* (https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#prop-drilling)